# Where does the Bible say to read itself?

Tags: bible, biblical-basis

It seems rather basic, but I'm having trouble finding verses that say to read God's Word often. It seems like something that Paul said quite a few times, and it's obviously a good thing, but I can't find any specific verses. Can someone help me?

Comment: 1st Peter, if I remember correctly, has some relevant exhortation towards the end of chapter 1 and beginning of chapter 2.

Comment: The OT was and oral tradition only written down during the years of captivity.

Comment: @DanAndrews - just a brief word of caution ... "oral tradition" does not mean that nothing was written down but that the significance of the content was placed on the passing on from generation to generation in oral form.

Comment: Verse identification questions are explicitly off-topic now. Ref: [Where's the line with the "verse-identification" tag?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/4200)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think there are any verses in the Bible that say "read the Bible", since the Bible as one book is a concept that came after the books were written.

But the following are some of the verses that talk about reading God's word or His teachings.

> 8 This book of the law shall not depart from your mouth, but you shall
>   meditate on it day and night, so that you may be careful to do
>   according to all that is written in it; for then you will make your
>   way prosperous, and then you will have success. Joshua 1:8 NASB

The Psalms have a lot on meditating on God's law.

> 1 How blessed is the man who does not walk in the counsel of the
>   wicked,  Nor stand in the path of sinners,  Nor sit in the seat of
>   scoffers!  2 But his delight is in the law of the LORD,  And in His
>   law he meditates day and night. Psalm 1: 1-2 NASB

And of course the famous [Psalm 119](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%20119&version=NASB), I'd suggest you read all of Psalm 119:

> 12 Blessed are You, O LORD;  Teach me Your statutes.  13 With my lips
>   I have told of  All the ordinances of Your mouth.  14 I have rejoiced
>   in the way of Your testimonies,  As much as in all riches.  15 I will
>   meditate on Your precepts  And regard Your ways.  16 I shall delight
>   in Your statutes;  I shall not forget Your word. Psalm 119: 12-16 NASB

That's all I can think of for now. But I will update this answer as I remember/find more.

Comment: Also, Deuteronomy 18-21.

Comment: Acts 17:11 seems somewhat relevant: "Now the Bereans were of more noble character than the Thessalonians, for they received the message with great eagerness and *examined the Scriptures* ***every day*** to see if what Paul said was true." (NIV, emphasis added).

Comment: Those all seem OT references where it speaks of learning/following/meditate over the law etc.

Answer (score 1):

Isaiah 28:10New King James Version (NKJV)

10 For precept must be upon precept, precept upon precept,
Line upon line, line upon line,
Here a little, there a little.”

Comment: Which denomination?

Comment: Please click [edit] to expand on your thoughts. There is not enough information here. You need to explain why the verse answers the question because it is not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Study to show thyself approved to God, a worker who needed not be ashamed. Rightly divided the word of truth.

II Timothy 2:15

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! I hope you'll spend some time browsing the questions and answers here. For a quick orientation to this site, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For some tips on writing good answers, please see: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)